# Nullpointer exception on Hashmap for CustomListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

I cant for the life of me figure this out. I just want to add some custom data into a listview with my Hashmap .

The process is that I put the info in a Hashmap, then I put the hashmap into an ArrayList - This causes a NullPointerException, and I dont know how to fix this.

```
public class RecipeDownload extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> FoodItems;
    public static String TitleofFood = "TitleofFood";
    public static String LinktoRecipe = "LinktoRecipe";
    public static String IngredientsofRecipe = "IngredientsofRecipe";
    public static String ThumbnailofFood = "thumbnail";


    public HashMap<String, String> RecipeItems = new HashMap<String, String>();


    EditText SearchField;
    Button ResearchButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.recipedownload);

        // Declaration of Button "Refreshbutton".
        ResearchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RefreshButton);

        // Declaration of EditText "SearchField"
        SearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SearchField);

        SearchField.setSelected(false);

        SearchField.setText(MainActivity.ItemToSearch);

        // Execute ConnectionCheck
        CheckConnection();

        // Recipe List Context Menu
        //registerForContextMenu(RecipeList);   


        RecipeItems.put(TitleofFood, "href");
        RecipeItems.put(LinktoRecipe, "href");
        RecipeItems.put(IngredientsofRecipe, "ingredients");
        RecipeItems.put(ThumbnailofFood, "thumbnail");

        FoodItems.add(RecipeItems);


    }
```

This creates a NullPointerException at row 71.

```
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.paul.barcoder/org.paul.barcoder.RecipeDownload}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at org.paul.barcoder.RecipeDownload.onCreate(RecipeDownload.java:71)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
09-04 16:16:46.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10372):    ... 11 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize `FoodItems`. You didn't.

```
 FoodItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

BTW, start all your variable names with lowercase.

Comment: please, don't waste your time on post question in SO, set braking point and verify why it's `null`

Comment: Ill look into using breaking points. I use Eclipse and havent figured it out (googled it now) on how to use it in Eclipse yet. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the foodItems as it was not Initialized . So you try to add and get nullPointer Eception

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> FoodItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

you haven't  initialize **FoodItems**

USe :

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> FoodItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Comment: Thank you Piyush! You always forget the simplest or smallest of things.